# Split dataset in R into 3 subsets: lower 25%, middle 50% and top 25%

Tags: r, subset

how do I subset data.frame data into three parts based on the values of one column? I want to show the u shape of a curve by building means within the different subsets. 
I already figured how to get a random top and bottom value, and how to get the top x and bottom x percent.. (e.g. 25%/50%/25%)

```
low.x <- top_n(final_data, -100, final_data$variablex)
high.x <- top_n(final_data, 100, final_data$variablex)
```

OR (sth. like... still gives me the wrong output for low.x)

```
n <- 25
low.x <- subset(final_data, final_data$variablex < quantile(final_data$variablex, prob = 1 - n/100))
high.si <- subset(final_data, final_data$variablex > quantile(final_data$variablex, prob = 1 - n/100))
```

But... How do I build the subsets based on lower 25%, main 50% and top 75%?

Thank you!

Comment: `subset(final_data,variablex<quantile(final_data$variablex,0.25)` should work...

Comment: Without having a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I'll guess that you can use `quantile` to find the break values, then use that as the `breaks` argument to `cut`

Answer (score 3):

Create a grouping variable `g` based on the quantiles `quant` and then split the data by it.  The input need not be sorted.

```
x <- 1:12 # test data

quant <- quantile(x, c(0, .25, .75, 1))
g <- cut(x, quant, include.lowest = TRUE, lab = c("lo", "mid", "hi"))
split(x, g)
```

giving:

```
$`lo`
[1] 1 2 3

$mid
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$hi
[1] 10 11 12
```

### quantcut

This could alternately be done in a more compact form using [quantcut](https://rdrr.io/cran/gtools/man/quantcut.html) from gtools.  This also does more sophisticated processing of duplicates.

```
library(gtools)

g <- quantcut(x, c(0, .25, .75, 1), lab = c("lo", "mid", "hi"))
split(x, g)
```

Comment: I'd use `findInterval` (more efficient) instead of `cut`.

Comment: Good idea if performance is critical but `cut` is more flexible being able to assign labels and the performance is so fast that with x = 1:1000 system.time shows the entire processing at taking 0 seconds so the speed advantage may be negligible.